# Measure String in MigraDoc TextFrame

Tags: c#, asp.net, migradoc

I've already tried asking the question on their forums but as yet to have received a response, hope someone can help me on here.

I have setup a custom report screen in asp.net where people can drag labels and fields and Migradoc produces this accordingly by using textframes and top/left/width/height properties to lay them out in the same place they were dragged/resized to. This all works great however one issue I have is if the text is longer than the textframe it runs off the page and I need the page to move on accordingly whilst retaining the other objects in place.

I can use the below code to measure a string:

```
Style style = document.Styles["Normal"];
TextMeasurement tm = new TextMeasurement(style.Font.Clone());
float fh = tm.MeasureString(value, UnitType.Millimeter).Height;
float fw = tm.MeasureString(value, UnitType.Millimeter).Width;
```

But it's only useful for comparing the width against the frame and not the height because it could be different once put into a smaller area.  Does anyone know how I can measure this string based on bound width/height values i.e. within a text frame.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `CreateBlocks()` method in the `XTextFormatter` class and how it calls MeasureString in a loop to break the text to multiple lines.

I'm afraid you have to implement such a loop yourself.

Or maybe use the `PrepareDocument()` method of the `DocumentRenderer` class to let MigraDoc do the work and just query the dimensions when it's done.

BTW: a similar question had been asked at the forum before:
http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=3590#p3590
Answer includes some source code.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this (using I-liked-the-old-stack-overflow's link) is to add the [PdfWordWrapper class](https://pastebin.com/Vee5Bugs) to your project and then calculate the dimensions of your text as follows:

```
var wrapper = new PdfWordWrapper(g, contentWidth); //g is your XGraphics object

wrapper.Add("My text here", someFont, XBrushes.Black);
wrapper.Process();
var dimensions = wrapper.Size; //you can access .Height or .Width
//If you want to reuse the wrapper just call .Clear() and then .Add() again with some new text
```